# Can't output the result in after if

Tags: ruby

I want to make this simple program that returns the weight quantity by choosing the units. When I run the program it runs with no problems and asks the two questions in `if` but doesn't return the `value`

Here is my code:

```
puts "What is your starting weight and ratio unit?
1:kg.m/h
2:gm.m/s
3:mm.m/s"

inputing_unit = gets.chomp

puts "What is your ending weight and ratio unit?
1:kg.m/h
2:gm.m/s
3:mm.m/s"

ending_unit = gets.chomp

if inputing_unit == 1 and ending_unit == 1 then
  puts "What is your weight?"
  input_weight = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "What is your ratio?"
  input_ratio = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "Your moving value is #{input weight * input_ratio}"
end
```

Comment: post code, not images of code

Comment: show show show your code...

Comment: i'm new to the website sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from that screenshot in the beginning of the description on pre-last line where is your puts statement there is a typo `#{input weight * input_ratio}`. You should change `...#{input weight...` to `...#{input_weight...` (with a dash).

Comment: Still it just asks for the first two questions.

Comment: I believe that you miss type conversion to integer. Your if statement should start like this `if inputing_unit.to_i == 1 and ending_unit.to_i == 1 then`

Comment: It worked,thank you man :D

Comment: Or you can write `inputing_unit == '1'` etc